# Cake PHP AclExtras Model field not populated

Tags: cakephp, acl

H,
I ran the AclExtras plugin for cakephp to automatically create my acos records. This ran fine, however, the model (and foreign key) fields are all set to null, including the root acos.
I'm guessing this isn't correct.

Any ideas why this has happened/how to fix?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this was right all along, and the model/foreign key cells remain empty (at least in my case)
This wasn't extremely clear in the documentation, however.